# `simulate` - Fails on testing, Not able to figure out the issue

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I do a simple testing using `jest`, all works fine expect a single issue. I am getting an error as

`expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("new comment");`

`fails.` not able to figure out the issue. any one help me?

here is my test code :

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import CommentBox from "components/CommentBox";

let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = mount(<CommentBox />);
});

afterEach(() => {
  wrapper.unmount();
});

it("has a text area and button", () => {
  expect(wrapper.find("textarea").length).toEqual(1);
  expect(wrapper.find("button").length).toEqual(1);
});

describe("the text area", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper.find("textarea").simulate("change", {
      target: { value: "new comment" }
    });
    wrapper.update();
  });
  it("has a text area that users can type in ", () => {
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("new comment");
  });

  it("when form is submitted, text area gets emptied", () => {
    wrapper.find("form").simulate("submit");
    wrapper.update();
    expect(wrapper.find("textarea").prop("value")).toEqual("");
  });
});
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/52m9374zll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your component you've made a typo

```
handleChange = event => {
  this.setState({ comment: event.target.vaue });
};
```

It should be `value` not `vaue`